# Modifying text in Excel file

Tags: java, jxl

I want to modify a excel file. I am unable to do that. 
I do some calculations and get an answer. I want to store that answer in the excel file. Again open it, store it and save it.

But, here, I am unable to do it.
Every time I get one value and I want to store that value in excel and then again open it and store it.

```
static int count=0;

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    try {
       for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
       update(i);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

public static void update(int i) throws BiffException, IOException, RowsExceededException, WriteException
{
    count++;
    Workbook existingWorkbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("try.xls"));
    WritableWorkbook workbookCopy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("try2.xls"), existingWorkbook);
    WritableSheet sheetToEdit = workbookCopy.getSheet(0);

    Label l = new Label(4, count, String.valueOf(i));
    sheetToEdit.addCell(l);

    workbookCopy.write();
    workbookCopy.close();
    existingWorkbook.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works, but I don't know if you are doing what you think you are doing.  Each time through, I see try2.xls is being updated correctly.  The problem is that on the next loop, you are reading in the original file try.xls again and then copying and writing anew.  At the end of 5 iterations, you would see the number 4 in the appropriate cell, but not 0-3 because those files have now been overwritten.

The loop should be moved inside the update method so that all the writes take place on the same workbook open/close.  Then you should see all five values in the try2.xls output workbook like you expect.